# Multithreading in C# sqlite

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite

I am building a C# wpf application and using a Sqlite database. Let's say I have 25 secondary threads waiting to perform an insert operation, and the main thread is trying to perform a select operation at the same time.

I could be wrong, but the main thread will have to wait a while.
How can I make sure the database is locked in my log files? How can I ensure the main thread has the highest priority so that my UI doesn't get blocked?

I am using the `DBContext` object to perform database operations.

Comment: Show us some code, and tell us why it is not working as it should. Explain **clearly** what you want, and what you want from us.

Comment: I want the main thread to get the highest priority and other threads to wait while performing the database operation so that my UI is not blocked. As i perform an action on my UI, I get database locked exception

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A clever use of `ReaderWriterLockSlim` will definitely help you improve performance.

```
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim _readerWriterLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    private DataTable RunSelectSQL(string Sql)
    {
        DataTable selectDataTable = null;
        try
        {
            _readerWriterLock.EnterReadLock();                
            //Function to acess your database and return the selected results
        }
        finally
        {
            _readerWriterLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
        return selectDataTable;
    }

    private DataTable RunInsertSQL(string Sql)
    {
        DataTable selectDataTable = null;
        bool isbreaked = false;
        try
        {
            _readerWriterLock.EnterWriteLock();
            if (_readerWriterLock.WaitingReadCount > 0)
            {
                isbreaked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //Function to insert data in your database
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _readerWriterLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }

        if (isbreaked)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            return RunInsertSQL(Sql);
        }
        return selectDataTable;
    }
```

Try this it will, improve your responsiveness and you have `Select` query to fire having higher priority over `Insert` SQL.

Please note, if some insertion is already running then Select will at least wait for that insertion to complete.
This code will always give priority to `SELECT` over `INSERT`.

**One more point**, never perform the **long ongoing operation** on main thread like you have **selecting from database**, rather perform the operation in background and then reflect the latest results on UI using main thread. This will ensure that your UI will never freeze.

**EDIT** There can be a **starvation** case where all `INSERT` may be waiting, if there are continuous `SELECT` queries being fired without any gap.
But I believe in your case, this will not happen as the `UI` will not always be refreshing to get the latest changes so frequently without any time slice in between.

Comment: Still not works, main thread is still blocked for a noticeable amount of time, at a time maximum 25 rows are inserted in the database, So i guess, main thread shouldn't wait for considerable amount of time

Comment: Thread priority has nothing to do with the database access. Serialized access will always _queue_ your transactions using a mutex.

Comment: @dbw nice way to have replacement for some kind of priority queue

Comment: If you have an `insert` ongoing and you start a `select`, the `select` will still have to wait. All a readwritterlock does is make it so that many reads can be concurrent but while a write lock is help, everything is blocked.

Comment: @Gusdor this point was already mentioned in my earlier edit, but with last edit I incidentally removed it

Comment: @dbw it doesn't fix the issue even a tiny bit.

Comment: @Gusdor just try to use the code and if you think so it will not improve the performance, then try it with bigger number of iterations you will definitely see improvement.

Comment: @dbw have you tried it? How about with an SQLlite database attached? This is a homeopathic answer (smoke and mirrors).

Answer (score 3):

What mode are you running the databae in?

> SQLite support three different threading modes:
>
> 1. Single-thread. In this mode, all mutexes are disabled and SQLite is unsafe to use in more than a single thread at once.
> 2. Multi-thread. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads provided that no single database connection is used
>      simultaneously in two or more threads.
> 3. Serialized. In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads with no restriction.
>
> **The default mode is serialized.**

http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

It would seem that Multi-Thread is the one you want. Serializing database access is *slow*.

Comment: Will check it, but why is the whole database getting locked, I am performing the select statement in a different table and insert on different and  both the tables are totally independent of other. So table locking makes sense but database locking doesnt makesw sense. Is there way to change that setting?

Comment: @yshooooo The documentation I linked describes how to change the mode of operation. How you implement that depends largely on how you are creating your connection. The default mode (serialized) fully locks the database for each transaction. This gives total thread safety, regardless of usage.

Comment: I am running into a problem with a website running on IIS7. Multiple requests come in simultaneously, and I'm getting 'Database is locked' errors. I do not see how to set the multi-thread mode. The documentation describes it for C/C++, but not in C#.

Comment: @pwrgreg007 i'd always recommend running a database server for web applications. SQLite is for embedded deployments. This probably isn't immediately helpful but will solve problems in the long run.

Comment: I'm posting this in hopes that someone will find it useful.  Note that we use this local/back-end/embedded DB for state info only. We also use SQL Server for the main DB, but we wanted state info local to the site and not have to worry about network issues. This site talks to devices (actually timeclocks), not people and we need a way to track events like sending biometric information.  The database had grown to over 250MB so the size was causing massive slowdown in SQLite. When I purged one large table of past state information and did a cleanup on it, the 'database locked' errors went away.

Comment: One other note: It appears that our application is handling multiple threads. I do not see a way to set threading mode in C#. I am using a common connection for all read operations, and create/dispose new connections for all write operations. It appears to work fine. I recommend using "using" blocks around all transient connections so they are disposed of properly.

Comment: How does threading mode interact with SQLite client driver connection pooling?

Answer (score 2):

A had exactly the same problem in my multithreaded caching subsystem
It looks like it is something like only 'System.Data.SQLite' library issue

Adding this (found with reflector)

"...;Version=3;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=100;"

to connection string solved the issue.