# Does Multithreading caused data reading from SQL Lite to be inaccurate?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, invalidoperationexception

I don't know how to exactly explain my problem, but the thing is I want to read data value from SQL Lite database, if I run only one thread, the data read from the sqllite database will be above 99% accurate.

```
Thread thr27 = new Thread(ListAFromTester11);
thr27.Start();
```

But if I run more than one thread, the accuracy of data read from sqllite database will be dropped down to 95%.

```
 Thread thr27 = new Thread(ListAFromTester11);
 thr27.Start();

 Thread thr28 = new Thread(ListAFromTester27);
 thr28.Start();

 Thread thr29 = new Thread(ListAFromTester8);
 thr29.Start();

 Thread thr30 = new Thread(ListAFromTester25);
 thr30.Start();
```

Below is the example of ListAFromTester25

```
public void ListAFromTester25()
    {
        bool m_bSuccT = false;

        while (!m_bSuccT)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(42000);

            m_listA_25.Clear();
            m_bSuccT = m_dbClient.DownloadSummaryFromDB_25(m_listA_25);

            if (m_bSuccT)
            {
                m_listB_25.Clear();
                m_bSuccT = m_dbClient.DownloadListSiteFromDB(m_listB_25, 25);

                if (m_bSuccT)
                {
                    m_bD10_25 = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is the example of DownloadListSiteFromDB(m_listB_25, 25)

```
public bool DownloadListSiteFromDB(List<StructB> list, Int32 D10ID)
    {
        if (D10ID == 1)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_1;
        else if (D10ID == 3)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_3;
        else if (D10ID == 4)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_4;
        else if (D10ID == 5)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_5;
        else if (D10ID == 6)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_6;
        else if (D10ID == 7)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_7;
        else if (D10ID == 8)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_8;
        else if (D10ID == 9)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_9;
        else if (D10ID == 10)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_10;
        else if (D10ID == 11)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_11;
        else if (D10ID == 12)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_12;
        else if (D10ID == 13)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_13;
        else if (D10ID == 14)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_14;
        else if (D10ID == 15)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_15;
        else if (D10ID == 16)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_16;
        else if (D10ID == 18)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_18;
        else if (D10ID == 19)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_19;
        else if (D10ID == 21)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_21;
        else if (D10ID == 22)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_22;
        else if (D10ID == 25)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_25;
        else if (D10ID == 26)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_26;
        else if (D10ID == 27)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_27;
        else if (D10ID == 31)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_31;
        else if (D10ID == 32)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_32;
        else if (D10ID == 33)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_33;
        else if (D10ID == 34)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_34;
        else if (D10ID == 35)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_35;
        else if (D10ID == 36)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_36;
        else if (D10ID == 37)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_37;
        else if (D10ID == 38)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_38;
        else if (D10ID == 39)
            m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_39;
        
        //
        try
        { //change query value for pressure_bin from 2.31 to 1.00
            //<niq> 15/09/2021 change query value for temperature_bin from 2.32 to 3.50
            string sql = @" SELECT Slot,
              SUM(CASE WHEN BinName = 'continuity_bin' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Continuity',
              SUM(CASE WHEN BinName = 'temperature_bin' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Temperature',
              SUM(CASE WHEN BinName = 'pressure_bin' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Pressure',
              SUM(CASE WHEN BinName = 'pass' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Pass',
              SUM(CASE WHEN BinName = 'total' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Total', 
              CASE WHEN(
            CAST (SUM(CASE WHEN BinName = 'continuity_bin' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END )  AS FLOAT) /CAST (SUM(CASE WHEN BinName = 'total' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END )
            AS FLOAT) *100) > 1.92 Then 1 ELSE 0 END AS ContinuityTrigger,
            CASE WHEN(
            CAST (SUM(CASE WHEN BinName = 'pressure_bin' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END )  AS FLOAT) /CAST (SUM(CASE WHEN BinName = 'total' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END )  
            AS FLOAT) *100) > 1.00 Then 1 ELSE 0 END AS PressureTrigger,
            CASE WHEN(
            CAST (SUM(CASE WHEN BinName = 'temperature_bin' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END )  AS FLOAT) /CAST (SUM(CASE WHEN BinName = 'total' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END )  
            AS FLOAT) *100) > 3.50 Then 1 ELSE 0 END AS TemperatureTrigger,                  
              (Select Lot||SubLot FROM Data )as LotID, (Select Device FROM Data) as DeviceID, (Select State FROM Data )as D10Status
              FROM (SELECT CAST (0 as int) as Slot, BinName, Qty FROM BINNINGSITE0 where BinName in ('continuity_bin', 'temperature_bin','pressure_bin')
              UNION ALL
            SELECT CAST (0 as int), 'pass', IFNULL(Sum(Qty),0) FROM BinningSite0 Where BinName like '%pass%'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CAST (0 as int), 'total', IFNULL(Sum(Qty),0) FROM BinningSite0 Where Qty > 200
            union ALL
            SELECT CAST (1 as int), BinName, Qty FROM BINNINGSITE1 where BinName in ('continuity_bin', 'temperature_bin','pressure_bin')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CAST (1 as int), 'pass', IFNULL(Sum(Qty),0) FROM BinningSite1 Where BinName like '%pass%'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CAST (1 as int), 'total', IFNULL(Sum(Qty),0) FROM BinningSite1 Where Qty > 200
            union ALL
            SELECT CAST (2 as int), BinName, Qty FROM BINNINGSITE2 where BinName in ('continuity_bin', 'temperature_bin','pressure_bin')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CAST (2 as int), 'pass', IFNULL(Sum(Qty),0) FROM BinningSite2 Where BinName like '%pass%'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CAST (2 as int), 'total', IFNULL(Sum(Qty),0) FROM BinningSite2 Where Qty > 200
            union ALL
            SELECT CAST (3 as int), BinName, Qty FROM BINNINGSITE3 where BinName in ('continuity_bin', 'temperature_bin','pressure_bin')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CAST (3 as int), 'pass', IFNULL(Sum(Qty),0) FROM BinningSite3 Where BinName like '%pass%'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CAST (3 as int), 'total', IFNULL(Sum(Qty),0) FROM BinningSite3 Where Qty > 200)  AS A
            GROUP BY Slot ";

            using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnLocal))
            {
                m_dbConnLocal.Open();
                using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.GetString(11)== "R")
                        {
                            list.Add(
                                new StructB
                                {
                                    EquipmentName = "D10_" + D10ID.ToString(),
                                    SlotID = reader.GetInt32(0),
                                    Continuity = reader.GetInt32(1),
                                    Temperature = reader.GetInt32(2),
                                    Pressure = reader.GetInt32(3),
                                    Pass = reader.GetInt32(4),
                                    Total = reader.GetInt32(5),
                                    ContinuityTrigger = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetInt32(6)),
                                    PressureTrigger = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetInt32(7)),
                                    TemperatureTrigger = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetInt32(8)),
                                    LotID = reader.GetString(9),
                                    DeviceID = reader.GetString(10),
                                    D10Status = reader.GetString(11)
                                }
                            );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            list.Add(
                                new StructB
                                {
                                    EquipmentName = "D10_" + D10ID.ToString(),
                                    SlotID = reader.GetInt32(0),
                                    Continuity = 0,
                                    Temperature = 0,
                                    Pressure = 0,
                                    Pass = 0,
                                    Total = 0,
                                    ContinuityTrigger = Convert.ToBoolean(0),
                                    PressureTrigger = Convert.ToBoolean(0),
                                    TemperatureTrigger = Convert.ToBoolean(0),
                                    LotID = "",
                                    DeviceID = "",
                                    D10Status = "E"
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DataProcessor.WriteLog("Error Catching", "DownloadListSiteFromDB: DB Error D1 - Exception: " + D10ID + " " + ex.Message);
            //MessageBox.Show("DB Error D1 - Exception: " + D10ID +ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            m_dbConnLocal.Close();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In multithreading, the line **m_dbConnLocal.Open();** will have error as below

```
InvalidOperationExecution Occured : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

This is snippet of my dbconnection.

```
    SQLiteConnection m_dbConnLocal_31 = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=\\\\\\\\sklplfs03\\D10Devprogs\\D10_Monitor\\D10_31.db;;version=3;new=False;Timeout=30000;datetimeformat=CurrentCulture");       
    SQLiteConnection m_dbConnLocal_32 = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=\\\\\\\\sklplfs03\\D10Devprogs\\D10_Monitor\\D10_32.db;version=3;new=False;Timeout=30000;datetimeformat=CurrentCulture");
    SQLiteConnection m_dbConnLocal_33 = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=\\\\\\\\sklplfs03\\D10Devprogs\\D10_Monitor\\D10_33.db;version=3;new=False;Timeout=30000;datetimeformat=CurrentCulture");
```

So should I change the way I write these connection strings in separate variable and use Dictionary<int, DbConnection> instead?

I do not know how to solve this, I am stucked. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I'm no SQL expert, but when I used devexpress, the best practice recommended using a pattern called "Unit of Work". My understanding was that it would only commit the changes at the end when it was resolved, but as you were running the query. I assume this was to help with thread safety. There is probably a similar thing for SQL lite.

Comment: With SQLite, it depends what your settings are. It might or might not be thread safe (see [here](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html)). For writing to SQLite from multiple threads, there is already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001129/multithreading-in-c-sharp-sqlite). For setting multithreaded mode, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814066/how-to-set-threading-mode-in-sqlite-with-entity-framework).

Comment: What exactly Unit of Work do? So basically the type of threads I am using may affect the accuracy of the acquired data? For example, if I direct query from MYSQL/SQLite db, I get qty 100, but in this case, in this multithreaded environment, I will get lower qty like 70.

Comment: There is a description of the Unit Of Work pattern [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/unit-of-work-in-repository-pattern/). There are a lot of missing details from the code we can see. One example: if the `List<StructB>` in your example function is shared across threads then the list will become corrupted. Another: the logic behind putting `DbConnection` in separate variables instead of using a `Dictionary<int, DbConnection>`. However, our help is going to be limited without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have added some snippets of how I declare the variable for dbconnection string, like you said I should change it and use Dictionary<int, DbConnection instead?

Comment: `m_dbConnLocal = m_dbConnLocal_1;` So you are changing field values, in a method that is called from multiple threads? That's definitely not going to do what you want.